# update multiple textarea into mysql db in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have textarea in the UI which i display text inside it from db and the user edits it and clicks on update button.

```
while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM,PDO::FETCH_ORI_NEXT)){

<textarea  id= <?php echo $row5[0]; ?> name='upAncText[]' rows=1 cols=40> <?php echo $row5[1]; ?> </textarea><br/> 

}
```

Now when i click on update i have to read the id and texarea value inorder to insert into DB. could anyone let me know how to do this in php?

Comment: This is the subject of every basic PHP/mySQL tutorial. You might be better of systematically going through one of them, as there are some pitfalls to this (e.g. XSS attacks and SQL injection)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your textarea to something like this:

```
// Are you sure you want $row5 and not $row ?
<textarea name="upAncText[<?= $row5[0]; ?>]"></textarea>
```

Now, when you grab `$_POST['upAncText']`, it will be an array with keys that are the textarea ID and values that are the user input.

FYI, `<?= ?>` is shorthand for `<?php echo ?>`